# Calling Prestashop postProcess method

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm actually developing a payment method module for **Prestashop 1.7** but now I'm stuck with the **postProcess()** method on my **payment** page, the method is being called immediately when the payment page loads. Do you know why this is happening? My **payment.tpl** its a simple html form to perform a POST request.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Its needed a validation because the postProcess runs after init() and before initContent():

```
public function postProcess()
{
    if (!empty($_POST))
    {
    // Magic here!
    }
}
```